# "Through" vs "throughout."

Tags: word-choice

How is the meaning of a sentences affected by chosing one of those words?

For instance, what's the different between

> The screech cicadas reverberated through the forest.

and

> The screech cicadas reverberated throughout the forest.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[Through](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/through)** means

> going in or starting at one side and coming out or stopping at the other side of: *a path through the wood*

**[Throughout](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/throughout?q=throughout)** means

> in every part of (a place or object)

There is a good deal of overlap, and either would be appropriate in many circumstances. *Through* often has a sense of *one end to the other*, while *throughout* suggests *into every corner*.

The latter gives a feeling of being more pervasive than the former.

Answer (score 8):

"Throughout" means through the whole area. So if you said "The screech cicadas reverberated throughout the forest," that means that most or all of the forest heard the noises.

If you said "Through the forest," that just says that the noise was heard in some of the forest, not all of it, as in, it went from one side to the other, as mentioned by Bib.